# Makefile Secondary Expansion

Tags: makefile, gnu, expansion

The gnu manual section 3.8 says:

"During the secondary expansion of explicit rules, `$$@` and `$$%` evaluate, respectively, to the file name of the target and, when the target is an archive member, the target member name. The `$$<` variable evaluates to the first prerequisite in the first rule for this target. `$$^` and `$$+` evaluate to the list of all prerequisites of rules that have already appeared for the same target (`$$+` with repetitions and `$$^` without). The following example will help illustrate these behaviors:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
foo: foo.1 bar.1 $$< $$^ $$+ # line #1
foo: foo.2 bar.2 $$< $$^ $$+ # line #2
foo: foo.3 bar.3 $$< $$^ $$+ # line #3
```

In the first prerequisite list, all three variables ($$<, $$^, and $$+) expand to the empty
string."

My question: Why does the `$$<` expand to empty string? The paragraph above says the it should evaluate to the first requisite to the first rule for this target. Wouldn't that be foo.1 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The manual is misleading, possibly due to a typo. The first of the two sentences:

> The $$< variable evaluates to the first prerequisite in the first rule for this target. 
>   $$^ and $$+ evaluate to the list of all prerequisites of rules that have already appeared
>   for the same target ($$+ with repetitions and $$^ without).

should be be qualified, like the second, by appending the words: "that has already appeared".

You can verify that this correctly describes the behaviour by running two makefiles:

**Make 1**

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
foo: foo.1 $$<
    @echo $+
```

The output is:

```
foo.1
```

showing that `$$<` has expanded to the empty string. Then:

**Make 2**

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
foo: foo.1
foo: foo.2 $$<
    @echo $+
```

Now the output is:

```
foo.2 foo.1 foo.1
```

Here, the explicit prerequisites `foo.1` and `foo.2` from the first and second
rules for target `foo` are combined, which accounts for the initial `foo.2 foo.1`
of the output. And in addition, `$$<` in the second rule is expanded to the first
prerequisite `foo.1` of the *previous* rule, which accounts or the final `foo.1`
of the output.

Comment: Note from the future: someone dropped the phrase "that have already appeared" in the GNU manual in italics, nice job Mike.  https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion

Comment: Note: make 3.81 is the last version where the example labelled "Make 2" works. From 3.82 on, the behaviour is different. https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?63125